# Размытие Label при перерисовке

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

`Label` привязан к позициям курсора мыши (как подсказка).

Если у `Label` граница `BorderThickness="1"`, то текст чёткий и всё отлично смотрится.

Но вот если `BorderThickness="0.5"`, а хотелось бы именно так, то текст размывается при передвижениях.

Как быть? Или это не вылечить?

Comment: UseLayoutRounding или там SnapsToDevicePixels пробовали?

Comment: @VladD попробовал, по прежнему размытие есть

Comment: А если положить вместо Label Grid, а в него уже Border нужной толщины и Label без границы одно на другом?